# How to apply multiple Conditions in Java streams

Tags: java, list, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a list of `Person`.

I want to find a person either has *employment* with the *maximum age*, else return any person the with *maximum age*.

I have written the following piece of code.

Is this fine or can have better approach.

```java
List <Person> personList;
    
Person person = personList.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.isEmployed())
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))
    .orElse(personList.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))
                .orElse(null));
```

Comment: What you get then?

Comment: You can sort first and get first one . Ex: `persons.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::isEmployed).thenComparing(Person::getAge)).findFirst();`

Comment: Why sort when the problem is already being solved in 2 pass (O(n)) or even one pass as in answer below?

Comment: @Akshay For the sake of readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a list of Person. I want to find a person either have employment with maximum age else return person with maximum age.

It can be done in a *single pass* through the list by creating an *intermediate map*, using collector [`partioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)) and providing collector [`maxBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy(java.util.Comparator)) as the downstream.

This combination will create a *map* containing *two entries* with keys `false` and `true` and *values* of type `Optional<Person>`. Because `maxBy()` produces an optional result.

Firstly, we have to get rid of empty optional by applying `filter()`.

Then we can sort these entries in *reversed order by key*, so that `true` will come before `false` (*the natural order: `false -> true`*). I.e. *employed person* having the greatest age will come first.

The last step is to apply `findFirst()` and extract the value from the resulting map entry.

Because we are sorting only *two* entries, it will not cause any tangible overhead and the code will run linear time (*reminder:* `maxBy()` *runs in* ***O(n)*** *time, performing a single pass through the data set*).

```
List<Person> personList =
    List.of(new Person(23, false), new Person(32, true),
            new Person(36, true), new Person(39, false),
            new Person(19, false), new Person(21, true));

Person person = personList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Person::isEmployed, // intermediate map Map<Boolean, Optional<Person>>
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().isPresent())
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<Boolean, Optional<Person>>comparingByKey().reversed())
    .findFirst()              // Optional<Map.Entry<Boolean, Optional<Person>>>
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // Optional<Optional<Person>>
    .map(Optional::get)       // Optional<Person>
    .orElse(null);

System.out.println(person);
```

*Output:*

```
Person {  age = 36, isEmployed = true }
```

[*A link to the Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rru)